# Android - Turning on "Don't keep activities" in Android Developer options duplicates my FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-activity

I was getting an error from a few users of my application that when clicking a listItem from my MainActivity would take them to a DetailActivity (which is the desired outcome), but if they press back or up, they would see a MainActivity that had everything duplicated (listView, menuItems). Someone suggested that maybe the activity is being killed because of memory so I went into Developer Options on my phone and turned on "Don't keep activities". This allowed me to replicate the problem. Now I have to figure out why everything is duplicated, but I'm a little stuck with which direction to go into. It's not like I'm creating the menu and layout in my onResume(). I'm doing everything in onCreate(). Does anyone have any suggestions on gracefully recovering from an activity that is not kept?

**EDIT 1:**

In response to the comment from @Tomer Mor

I have three activities total. A -> B-> C

MainActivity in this case is B and DetailActivity is C. My activity A is a "LoginActivity" that get's finish()'d after I successfully "login".

**EDIT 2:**

If it helps, my MainActivity is a FragmentActivity.

**EDIT 3:**

In response to @Doctoror Drive. My MainActivity extends FragmentActivity. MainActivity adds MyFragment.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setUpActionBar();
    Toast.makeText(this, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), 1).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.my_placement);

    myFragment = new MyFragment();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

I put a log inside of my onCreate of `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` and it get's called **ONCE.** I put a `Log.d()` in my `onCreateOptionsMenu()` of of `MyFragment.java` and it shows **TWICE!** So it IS being called twice, but I'm not sure how if it's only being created once.

**EDIT 4:**

```
03-24 14:17:37.038: E/MainActivity(26486): onCreate hit!
03-24 14:17:37.048: D/SherlockFragmentActivity(26486): [supportInvalidateOptionsMenu]
03-24 14:17:37.048: D/SherlockFragmentActivity(26486): [invalidateOptionsMenu]
03-24 14:17:37.048: D/ActionBarSherlock(26486): [dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu]
03-24 14:17:37.048: E/MyFragment(26486): onActivityCreated!
03-24 14:17:37.048: D/SherlockFragmentActivity(26486): [supportInvalidateOptionsMenu]
03-24 14:17:37.048: D/SherlockFragmentActivity(26486): [invalidateOptionsMenu]
03-24 14:17:37.048: D/ActionBarSherlock(26486): [dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu]
03-24 14:17:37.048: E/MyFragment(26486): onActivityCreated!
```

**EDIT 5:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState=null;
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    adapter = AnimalList.getAnimalAdapter();
    setListAdapter(adapter);



}
```

Comment: check in the manifast MainActivity launchMode param

Comment: It's your Fragments being duplicated, aren't they? Post your Activity's onCreate().

Comment: Don't start a new question onActivityCreated() is a method of the Fragment. You have two Fragments so it's called twice. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a Fragment while Activity restores it's state is a common bug.
You should add the Fragment only when the Activity's savedInstanceState s null, otherwise the FragmentManager adds it for you automatically and you end up with two fragment instanced being attached.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And the other bad practice is using members to access Fragments.
The Fragment's lifecycle can be a little different then activity, so myFragment member can point to obsolete Fragment instance at some point.
The proper way is whenever you need MyFragment, find it in a FragmentManager

```
//if you need to do something with MyFragment
public void doSomething() {
    final MyFragment myFragment = getMyFragment();
    // can be null if re-creating or not yet attached.
    if (myFragment != null) {
        myFragment.doSomething();
    }
}

private MyFragment getMyFragment() {
    return (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
}
```

Comment: Before I implement your answer... I'm still confused about how I have "two" fragments apparently. Android says `For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments.` http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html My MainActivity extends FragmentActivity is definitely destroyed because I have a Toast in onDestroy(). Should that cause my fragment to onDestroy() as well?

Comment: @user2676468 when Activity is destroyed by the system during lack of memory or when "dont keep activities" is set", the FragmentManager saves fragment information. When you restore it, the Activity restores states of the Views and FragmentManager restores all your fragments as they were when destroying. So you should never manually add Fragments on onCreate if savedInstanceState is not null.

Comment: Got it. I implemented the not null check, and now I have one instance of my menu (YES!), but my listView does not show up at all now. It was showing TWICE before =/ Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the ListView located? How do you populate it?

Comment: I setListAdapter() in MyFragment.java in `onActivityCreated()`. I populate it via an adapter.

Comment: How about setting it up in onCreateView() or onViewCreated()? If you need Activity reference you can safely call getActivity() in fragment's onCreate(), onCreateView() or onViewCreated()

Comment: I put all of my onActivityCreated code into onViewCreated, and I get the same result (one menu, no listView). I try to put it in my onCreateView() but I got a "Content view not yet created" error.

Comment: @user2676468 try it. If it doesn't work, post the code from onCreateView() so we can find the problem.

Comment: I've tried playing around with onCreateView(), but I just get an exception. I have run out of ideas. I do not understand how the onCreateOptionsMenu is called once, but the listView doesn't appear.

Comment: Post your ListView and it's Adapter initialization. The problem can be be there.

Comment: I seemed to have "fixed" it. In my onActivityCreated() I set `savedInstanceState = null;`  and then have my listView code and it runs fine. Any thoughts on doing that?

Comment: It's something you shouldn't do, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I don't see much problems. What doesn AnimalList.getAnimalAdapter() do? AnimalAdapter must not be a singleton.